# How to make it so it is not selecting the data first in Drop down Box

Tags: php, ms-access

I have an issue where the name is populating first. I am not sure how to create a blank selected field on this drop down Box.

```
<li id="li_7" >
            <label class="description" for="Contact">Contact</label>
            <div>
                <?php

    try {

    $dbName = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\fpdb\\staffing.mdb";
     $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};charset=UTF-8; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");

    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    $sql="SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, SCHEDULEPRIORTY  FROM tbl_USERS WHERE (SCHEDULEPRIORTY = 1) OR (SCHEDULEPRIORTY = 2) OR (SCHEDULEPRIORTY = 3)  order by FIRSTNAME";

    /* You can add order by clause to the sql statement if the names are to be displayed in alphabetical order */

    echo "<select id='Contact' name=Contact value=''>Contact</option>"; // list box select command
    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row){//Array or records stored in $row
    echo "<option value=$row[FIRSTNAME],$row[LASTNAME]>$row[FIRSTNAME]  $row[LASTNAME]</option>"; 

    /* Option values are added by looping through the array */ 
    }
    echo "</select>";// Closing of list box


    ?>
```

Comment: Select tag should not have an value-attribute. You have an </option> tag wihout an beginning option tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add something like this:

```
echo '<option value="none">Please select a user</option>';
```

... above this line:

```
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row){//Array or records stored in $row
```

Comment: I tried that it is all red not working only word not red is none

Answer (score 0):

```
/* You can add order by clause to the sql statement if the names are to be      displayed in alphabetical order */

echo "<select id='Contact' name='Contact'>"; // list box select command
echo "<option value=''>Contact</option>";

foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row){//Array or records stored in $row
    echo "<option value='$row[FIRSTNAME],$row[LASTNAME]'>$row[FIRSTNAME] $row[LASTNAME]</option>"; 

/* Option values are added by looping through the array */ 
}

echo "</select>";// Closing of list box
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<select id='Contact' name='Contact' >";
echo "<option value=''>[please select a contact]</option>";

foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row){    
    echo "<option value='". $row['FIRSTNAME']. "," . $row['LASTNAME']. "'>";
    echo $row['FIRSTNAME'] . " " . $row['LASTNAME'] . "</option>";     
}
echo "</select>";
```